# Javascript function from ASP.Net Code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to call javascript from the page code behind on a button click using the following code.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<script language=\"javascript\">");
                sb.Append("alert(\"Some Message\")");
                sb.Append("</script>");
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", sb.ToString());
```

But the javascript is not getting called.

All I want to achieve from this is a popup msg on button click. I dont want to prevent server code execution.

Comment: are you really aware of the difference between client- and serverside? ... nothing more to say ... really ...

Comment: I tried the same code in Page_Load and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using AJAX Update Panel. If so - you should use ScriptManager to execute your script:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<script language=\"javascript\">");
                sb.Append("confirm(\"Some Message\")");
                sb.Append("</script>");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                             page, 
                             page.GetType(),  
                             "Alert", 
                             sb.ToString(), 
                             true);
```

However, it will not prevent your server-side code from execution if user answer "No" in your Confirm window.

Comment: I dont want to prevent the server code execution. All I want is just a popup on button click

Comment: I am not using AJAX update Panel. Is there any way to call this without that?

Comment: yep try ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock();

Comment: Nadeem, i've tried RegisterClientScriptBlock from a test page and it works fine.  Could you give any more information or a full code sample?

Answer (score 0):

If your registering from a button event in an AJAX update panel, try;

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptName", sb.ToString(), true);
```

Cheers Tigger

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem once, all i wanted was to display a popup on `Send Email` button click. I achieved that doing following:

```
if(True)
{
 Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your e-mail sent successfully!');</script>");
}
else
{
  Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your e-mail sent Failed! Please Try Again');</script>");
}
```